# What is the easiest way to change the background-color of a Dojo Toggle Button as used in XPages

Tags: javascript, css, xpages

I've try to override the style class dijitTogglebutton and set the background-color in defined class but no luck.  Been able to remove the style class dijitToggleButton but is reinsert itself.  The Domino version is 10 fp4.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far :-)

Comment: My Styles didn't worked:
.ToggleButton{ 
/* background-color: transparent;
 background-color: white; */
 background-color: transparent!important;
 background: transparent!important; 
 background: none;
}

.ToggleButton:hover{
 background-color: transparent!important;
 background: transparent!important;  
}

Comment: Is that part of a CSS file that you load on your XPage?

Comment: Yes the part of the CSS file.
I got this overrides to work.  What I trying to accomplish is to just show the icons in the two toggle states.
.dijitToggleButton .dijitButtonNode{
 background-color: transparent!important;;
 background: transparent!important;;
}

.dijitToggleButtonHover .dijitButtonNode{

 background-color: transparent!important;
 background: transparent!important;
}

Comment: Are you sure that the CSS class is called ToggleButton (as your CSS shows) and not dijitToggleButton?

Comment: Yes, I can see the ToggleButton style in browser debug but it seems to have no affect.  Only when I override the dijitToggleButton and hover class does the background changes.  It looks like the dijit classes are applied to a child span and parent of the button where my class is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may work, as long as another dijitToggleButton isn't used on the page.
Set the background to transparent and unset the borders. Now I just need to adjust the size. Not sure if there better or easier way.
Thanks Henrik for helping my thinking process.

```
.dijitToggleButton .dijitButtonNode{
    background-color: transparent!important;;
    background: transparent!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: unset!important;
    -moz-box-shadow: unset!important;
    box-shadow: unset!important;
}`enter code here`

.dijitToggleButtonHover .dijitButtonNode{
    background-color: transparent!important;
    background: transparent!important;
}
```